# MySQL: Order By with time comparison result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I've table of bus routes with departure time column as **departtime**. I want to show listing in **ASC** order with **ORDER BY** **depattime** where **depattime** is 3 hours ago of current time.

Here is how I'm trying to do

```
        $this->db->order_by('departtime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 HOUR)','asc');
```

I also tried with **CASE** in order_by clause but then also couldn't get required result.

Here is demo Database[image]
Here is Result Screen[image]

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar you can check it now. I updated my question with database

Comment: your question is mixing ORDER BY with WHERE conditions - i think.  first restrict to the times you want then the ORDER BY is simple departtime ASC

Comment: You still haven't shown what result you're trying to get. You want the rows whose departure time is more than 3 hours from now to be shown first or last?

Comment: @Randy yeah it's. You can say that I need Where clause in Order by clause. Syntax wise it's not possible then how to sort list

Comment: Your desired results just seem to be ordered by departure time: 10:00, 10:30, 11:00. How is that related to the current time and 3 hours?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
 from table 
where departtime >= DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 3 HOUR) 
order 
 by departtime desc;
```

Guess this would work..

Comment: I works for me but I need display all times in such a way that route with departure time 3 hours ago from current time will display first and rest of will show end of list